# How to direct main page (index) from sub-folder page (image out)

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

My photo gallery site has thousands of html pages, most of them are only with large photos. That is when clicking small thumb, opens a new window with large photos.

This large view html pages has no navigations. I want to add 'home' and 'back to artist' navigation in these html pages.

```
www.mysite.tld/gallery/artist/name/event/(here stored large images and its html pages)
```

this same structure goes for other artist names too.

I am using dreamweaver templates. In template, to go back folder, I added..

```
<a href="../index.html">Back to Main</a>
```

..(here artist main folder)/(artist index).html

but when saving this template as html to different folder, this `"../index.html"` changes to `"../../../index.html"` which goes to main website index page :/

I can simply type `../index.html` in one page but the site has many artist folders with same structure.

so how to direct/link to artist page from its sub-folder html pages. Using javascript or any scripts?

Really sorry for this big message. Please dont down-vote because of my stupid question. Thank You.

EDIT :
I tried History back() Method but that's not working because if users come from search engine, there's no history to go back to main artist page.

In simple. You click a page from google and in that landed page (large image here), you need a navigation to visit the main gallery page with other images in small thumbs or to say event gallery page (which present in up-directory in my site). So to navigate to main gallery page, I am stuck here for "how to". May be I need to do in php or something :/

Answer (score 1):

One way of resolving this is to use absolute paths instead of relative paths.  Absolute paths start with `/`.

I'd suggest adding Dreamweaver as a tag to your question, to get the attention of Dreamweaver users who may recognise your situation and can help.

Comment: I tried that way but when adding only "/" dreamweaver automatically adds domain name in html (from template to saved html). 

I also tried /gallery/names/artist/index.html  but my site has many artists so it only work for one artist. I may have to put some regular expression to go up level directory but i am not expert there. Well, Thank you very much for the reply.. :)

Comment: You're welcome, I see you've added the `Dreamwaver` tag. Hopefully someone'll chip in with something good for this question.